# iPhone 7 wrongly installed display without a left margin on screen

Tags: iphone, display

Has anyone else encountered a new iPhone, where the display is wrongly installed into the device?

On the new iPhone 7 I got, there's no left margin in the screen?

Pic 1 (see how the operator bars in the top left corner nearly touch the edge)
Pic 2 (see "No sim" touches the left border):

[image]
[image]

ps. Tried rebooting & iOS update

Comment: It is suggested you visit the Apple Store or the authorised Apple reseller you bought the device from. It may still be covered under no questions return policy, and the least under the 1 year standard warranty.

Comment: I don't know where you are, but surely the consumer protections in your country must protect you from a failure. In Australia, this would be covered under the Consumer Law.

Comment: This edit that your employer installed armoured glass using a 3rd party should be given in an answer! The question should only contain the question, and answers should be posted as answers below.

Comment: grgarside:  I'll do that way next time!